# Can I reuse the Akismet API key used on old version of my website?

Tags: akismet

I have a site with old version of Akismet plugin. I'm doing a major update/reinstall and I need Akismet API key to reactivate the Akismet plugin. I didn't find the key neither hardcoded anywhere in the plugin code nor stored in the `wp_options` table in the database, where other Akismet variables are stored. I tried to google it out and all I found was to look at the e-mail where the API key was sent. I'm not the original webmaster, so this is not possible directly. I contacted the former webmaster, but he is not responding for several weeks, so I don't expect him to send me the key.

Can I retain the key somehow, or is my only option to get a new key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Akismet key is connected to your WordPress.com account or to your email address.

If you need to get the key again, just have it resent to you: https://akismet.com/resend/

Comment: I expect this to help a lot people, so +1. However, it doesn't apply to my case. Does it mean that we should associate the site with my account, instead of that of the former webmaster?  If the key is not website- but account-specific, then using the old key would make trouble in the future (necessity of contacting that guy in each situation like this). Add a brief note to confirm this and I'll also accept your answer.

Comment: I don't understand your question then. You should use the key connected to the person who owns the website.

Comment: the site is owned by a group of people. The "official" owner is the former webmaster, but who is "owner" is more complicated in our case. I agree the question is bad, since I asked the question I saw many times before on other webs ("How to retrieve lost API key?"), but what I really needed was "Whose API key should be used in our case?", which would require completely different wording and would likely be too localized.

Comment: If it's not owned by a single person, then it's likely a commercial site, and you need to purchase a key for it. https://akismet.com/account/upgrade/

Comment: In this case not - it's a site of a fantasy world produced by a group of enthusiasts; it is not intended to ever become commercial.